# How to solve error when I load sid with readGEBCO.bathy in R marmap?

Tags: r

I am using the R marmap package, and when I load the sid file, I keep getting this error:

```
sid<-readGEBCO.bathy(file="C:/Users/Desktop/GEBCO_2014_SID_2D_-72.2876_-29.6177_-71.2257_-28.392.nc", resolution=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
[1] "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar) in the file!" [1] "var (or dimvar) name: elevation"  
[1] "file name: C:/Users/Susannah Buchan/Desktop/GEBCO_2014_SID_2D_-72.2876_-29.6177_-71.2257_-28.392.nc" 
Error in vobjtovarid4(nc, varid, verbose = verbose, allowdimvar = TRUE) : Variable not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an updated version of `readGEBCO.bathy()` on GitHub. Setting the new `sid` argument to `TRUE` should now do the trick:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ericpante/marmap")

library(marmap)
sid<-readGEBCO.bathy(file="C:/Users/Desktop/GEBCO_2014_SID_2D_-72.2876_-29.6177_-71.2257_-28.392.nc", resolution=1, sid=TRUE)
```

This bugfix along with other minor improvements should be published on CRAN servers early July. Stay tuned!